# How can I capture the feed of a Space and embed it in an NSView similar to Mission Control Space previews?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, spaces, mission-control

What I'd like to do is display a Desktop preview of another Space the exact same way the current implementation of Spaces shows previews of all other Desktops.  I've provided a graphic at the bottom for visual reference.  You can see on Desktop 1 I'm on StackOverflow and on Desktop 2 I'm watching a video on youtube.  In Spaces, even if I'm on Desktop 1, I can still see the small preview of Desktop 2 with the video playing.  In short what I'd like to do is implement the same functionality in my application where I grab that same feed Spaces uses (where if a video were playing, I'd see it play) and put it in an NSView of my main application window.  Is this at all possible?

[image: Example of Spaces Desktop Preview]